# Returning right message for 2 radiobutton options

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a game which will feature a store. When a button is selected, a certain message must be returned according to the button pressed to buy. I now have the code below.
How can I make sure the right message gets returned(so for weapon, the weapon message, for protection, the protection message).

I was looking for a method to make only one radiobutton selectable, but I'm sure it's way more simple. Help is really appreciated, thanks!

Controller:

```
if (WeaponType != 0) {                      // buying weapon
            if (IsItemAllowed((int)WeaponType, gangster)) {
                if (gangster.Cash < WeaponPrice(WeaponType)) {
                    ViewBag.Message = "You don't have enough cash to buy this weapon";
                    return View();
                }
                gangster.Cash -= WeaponPrice(WeaponType);
                gangster.Weapon++;
                ViewBag.Message = "You have succesfully purchased this weapon";
            } else {
                ViewBag.Message = "You can't buy this weapon yet";
            }
        } else if (ProtectionType != 0) { // buying protection
            if (IsItemAllowed((int)ProtectionType, gangster)) {
                if (gangster.Cash < ProtectionPrice(ProtectionType)) {
                    ViewBag.Message = "You don't have enough cash to buy this protection";
                    return View();
                }
                gangster.Cash -= ProtectionPrice(ProtectionType);
                gangster.Protection++;
                ViewBag.Message = "You have succesfully purchased this protection";
            } else {
                ViewBag.Message = "You can't buy this protection yet";
            }
        }
```

view:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index")) {
    @Html.Button("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon01, false)@: .38 S&W Model 12<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon02, false)@: .45 M1911<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon03, false)@: Remington Model 11<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon04, false)@: .351 Winchester SL<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon05, false)@: Thompson Model 1921 <br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon06, false)@: Browning Automatic Rifle <br>
    @Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon07, false)@: Browning M2<br>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buy Weapon" />
    <br>
    @Html.RadioButton("ProtectionType", LocalStoreModel.StoreProtection.Protection01, false)@: Layered Fabric Vest<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("ProtectionType", LocalStoreModel.StoreProtection.Protection02, false)@: Metal Plate Vest<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("ProtectionType", LocalStoreModel.StoreProtection.Protection03, false)@: Ceramic Plate Vest<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("ProtectionType", LocalStoreModel.StoreProtection.Protection04, false)@: Armoured T-Ford<br>
    @Html.RadioButton("ProtectionType", LocalStoreModel.StoreProtection.Protection05, false)@: Armored Car (Custom)<br>
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" value="Buy Protection" />
    <br>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add an `id` tag to your `RadioButton` helper. If you look at the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538302%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) for the helper, you can see how to add HTML attributes to your radio button. The id should be the same for all radio buttons that are grouped together.

For example, your first two would look like this:

```
@Html.Button("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon01, false, new {id="weaponType"})@: .38 S&W Model 12<br>
@Html.RadioButton("WeaponType", LocalStoreModel.StoreWeapon.Weapon02, false, new {id="weaponType"})@: .45 M1911<br>
```